# Как можно заблокировать паролем вход в чужое или системное приложение и отключить уведомления от этого приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я пишу приложение которое показывает все приложения установленные на телефоне, оно должно блокировать вход в выбранные приложения, записанным пользователем, паролем. Нужная информация по поводу вывода всех приложений установленных на телефоне:

Шаблон для элементов списка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listApps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listApps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Создаем новый адаптер
        AppInfoAdapter adapter = new AppInfoAdapter(this,
                Utilities.getInstalledApplication(this), getPackageManager());
        // устанавливаем адаптер для ListView
        listApps.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Класс AppInfoAdapter

```
public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;
    private PackageManager mPackManager;

    public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List<ApplicationInfo> list, PackageManager pm) {
        mContext = c;
        mListAppInfo = list;
        mPackManager = pm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListAppInfo.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListAppInfo.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ApplicationInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

        View v = convertView;

        if(v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        // загружаем элементы из ресурсов
        ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
        TextView tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

        // назначаем данные (значки, имена программ и пакетов)
        ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
        tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));

        return v;
    }
}
```

Класс Utilities

```
public class Utilities {

    public static List<ApplicationInfo> getInstalledApplication(Context c) {
        return c.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    }
}
```

Как можно поставить пароль на чужое или системное приложение?

Comment: Для того, что бы предотвратить запуск других приложений. тебе как минимум нужно сделать свое приложение лаунчером. И перехватывать запуск. Но так ты только блокируешь запуск приложений пользователем. Системный запуск ты никак не заблокируешь